# Error load google maps with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fancybox

This is my html:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#g_map_container">Show Map</a>
<div id="g_map_container" style="height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
```

And my script:

```
load_map();
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    hideOnContentClick : false,
    fitToView          : true,
    width              : '100%',
    height             : '100%',
    autoSize           : false,
    closeClick         : false,
    openEffect         : 'none',
    closeEffect        : 'none',
    onComplete         : function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
});
```

This is function load_map()

```
function load_map() {
    mapDiv = document.getElementById('g_map_container');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0); // My address
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        panControl: false,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false
        },
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
}
```

This is result:
[image: error]

Comment: do you have : `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` inside head tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fixed size in your map container

```
 <div id="g_map_container" style="height:500px; width: 500px;"></div>
```

if work in this situation you must assign a proper width and heigth at all the container parent of your map div ..(no parent div must be without an assigned, also in percentage, width and height)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `%` in width or height of the gmap canvas. you should type fixed size, e.g. `400 x 500`. etc. Otherwise, it'll show you nothing.

**UPDATED:**
Besides, take a look at your code at:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0); // My address
```

Try to define concretely the latt and long inside it.